# Traverse XML Based upon their parent

Tags: jquery, xml-parsing

i am fetching xml by using ajax/jquery, suppose my xml is

```
<root>
 <parent name="p1">
  <child name="c1" value="1"/>
  <child name="c2" value="2"/>
 </parent>

 <parent name="p2">
  <child name="c3" value="3"/>
  <child name="c4" value="4"/>
 </parent>
</root>
```

now i want to read only values of child of "p2" not "p1"  i.e. (3,4),

normal jquery code  i.e.

```
$(result).find("child").each(function(){
 value1=$(this).attr("value");
 alert(value1);
});
```

is not working here... it will also return "1" & "2" which i dont want.

can anybody pls tell me, how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your `child` selector to be more specific

```
$(result).find("parent[name='p2'] child").each(function(){
 value1=$(this).attr("value");
 alert(value1);
});
```